# import sql server data in excel 2007 using C#

Tags: sql, sql-server, c#-4.0

Is it possible to import sql server data in to Excel using c#?

If so, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some links to help you out:

Links:

http://dotnetguts.blogspot.com/2007/12/export-datagrid-to-excel-in-aspnet.html

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173186(VS.80).aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Excel_and_C_.aspx

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302084

http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article1150-all-in-one-export-data-in-aspnet-gridview-to-doc-gridview-to-excel-gr-.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is possible even using C++ and ODBC :)

To do it in C#, you need to create Excel document object.
To create Excel Document object, you need first to create reference to Microsoft Excel Object Library. 
Then read the data from SQL Server using ADO.Net. Then insert this data into opened Excel document object.
Then you need to save this Excel document.